# Zip directory on windows and extract on Linux

Tags: php, linux, windows, php-ziparchive

I create zip file in windows with this code

```
$plugin_address="D:/processmaker-3.2.1-x/apps/processmaker/htdocs/cakephp/plugins";
$rootPath = $plugin_address."/".$R;
$zipFileName = $rootPath.'.zip';
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open($zipFileName, ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);

$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($rootPath),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY
);

foreach ($files as $name => $file)
{

    if (!$file->isDir())
    {

        $filePath = $file->getRealPath();
        $relativePath = substr($filePath, strlen($rootPath) + 1);

        $filePath=str_replace("\\","/",$filePath);

        $zip->addFile($filePath, $relativePath);
    }
}


$zip->close();
```

[image]
Zip file is correct...(image above)

Now i want extract this file in Ubuntu with this code

```
$zipAdress="/var/www/cakephp/plugins/backup/EstelamBasic.zip";
$plugin_address="/var/www/cakephp/plugins/EstelamBasic/";
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open($zipAdress);
if ($res === TRUE) {
  $zip->extractTo($plugin_address);
  $zip->close();
}
```

This code worked and extract zip file but does not create directory and sub directory.
This code set directory name in file name!

(extract code in windows is correct and create directory and sub directory and set file in directory)
[image]

Comment: On Ubuntu, the directory separator character is `/`, not \

Answer (score 2):

I use this function for zip on windows that worked extract on linux

```
 $rootPath = "/var/www/cakephp/plugins/EstelamBasic";
    $zipFileName = $rootPath.'.zip';
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    $zip->open($zipFileName, ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);

    addFolderToZip($rootPath."/", $zip, $zipdir = '');
    $zip->close();

    function addFolderToZip($dir, $zipArchive, $zipdir = ''){ 

        if (is_dir($dir)) { 
            if ($dh = opendir($dir)) { 

                //Add the directory 
                if(!empty($zipdir)) $zipArchive->addEmptyDir($zipdir); 

                // Loop through all the files 
                while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) { 

                    //If it's a folder, run the function again! 

                    if(!is_file($dir . $file)){ 
                        // Skip parent and root directories 
                        if( ($file !== ".") && ($file !== "..")){ 
                            addFolderToZip($dir . $file . "/", $zipArchive, $zipdir . $file . "/");
                        } 

                    }else{ 
                        // Add the files 
                        $zipArchive->addFile($dir . $file, $zipdir . $file); 

                    } 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    }
```